# SQL Error in Syntax near except

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to select persons who have an account at all branches of the city.
(With a SQL query)

```
SELECT A.customId 
FROM accountholder as A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
                   (SELECT name 
                    FROM branch 
                    WHERE city='LA') 
EXCEPT (SELECT C.branch 
        FROM accountholder AS B, account AS C 
        WHERE B.accountnumber = C.accountnumber 
              AND A.customId = B.customId));
```

Now I got:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT (SELECT C.branch FROM accountholder AS B, account AS C WHERE B.accountnumber=' at line 1

And I do not see the problem. Am I blind or just stupid?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Where in the MySQL manual did you find the `EXCEPT` operator?

Comment: In our script. But it also does not work with "not in".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, MySQL does not support the `EXCEPT` operation. You will have to rewrite your query.

You appear to be querying accountholders if there is no other branch in LA besides those branches at which the accountholder's accounts are held.

Here's a rough guess:

```
SELECT A.customId
FROM accountholder AS A
JOIN account AS C 
  ON A.accountnumber = C.accountnumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN branch AS B
  ON C.branch <> B.name AND B.city = 'LA'
WHERE B.city IS NULL;
```

I'm making some assumptions about your tables and columns and their relationships, so this query is just a guess. *Do not just run it blindly and expect it to work.* I ask you to use it as an example and confirm that the comparisons are being done correctly for your data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've never used "left outer join", maybe it's time to do this. In any case, there is no error. Thank you for this approach, I'll continue to work with it!

Comment: Using SQL without understanding joins (and their variations) is like using any other programming language without understanding `while` loops. It's a fundamental part of the language.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL does not use `EXCEPT`. Use [`NOT IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in).

```
SELECT A.customId 
FROM accountholder as A 
WHERE branch NOT IN ( 
(SELECT name FROM branch WHERE city='LA') 
AND branch NOT IN (SELECT C.branch FROM accountholder AS B, account AS C WHERE B.accountnumber = C.accountnumber AND A.customId = B.customId));
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'branch' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'. What does this mean?

Comment: Apparently there is no column named branch in the account table

Comment: Okay, now it shows me all customers outside the city ..
And when I change "not in" to "in", it shows me customers either in one branch of the city, or in the other..
I should start from the beginning. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL only supports `UNION` but not `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT`/`MINUS`

Adding these set operations has been a long standing feature request

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1309

You may want to vote "Affects me" on that bug report ...

Comment: This is not an answer and should be a comment

Comment: @JohnConde, I disagree -- this answers the question as it was stated, in that it explains the cause of the error. If the question is, "how do I make a different query to give the desired result" then that is only implied.